# Interact / interactive for a black box function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I have a blackbox function which accepts ~10 integer inputs. The function returns a pandas dataframe, and I would like to capture the output window (by using bbwidget.children) and display elsewhere in a Layout. So far interact/interactive seems the bet for this.

I have defined a list of widgets to use as inputs to the function; can I pass this list to interact/interactive? From my attempts so far, I need to specify ALL of the input widgets beforehand, and pass them all individually in a call to interactive.

Here's conceptually what I would like to do (just using the dictcomp in the function call to illustrate that each widget maps to a certain input):

```
widgetlist = [list of int input widgets]
inputlist = [list of function inputs]

def bbfunc(inputlist):
    return df

bbwidget = ipyw.interactive(bbfunc, {k:v for k,v in zip(widgetlist,inputlist)})
```

Is there some special syntax or option for a call to interact/interactive that could allow for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my own answer:

```
import ipywidgets as ipyw
from IPython.display import display

def f(x,y):
    return x + y

x,y = 0,0
xwidget = ipyw.IntSlider(min=-10,max=30,step=1,value=10)
ywidget = ipyw.IntSlider(min=-10,max=30,step=1,value=10)
widgetdict = {k:v for k,v in zip(('x','y'),(xwidget,ywidget))}
testwidg = ipyw.interact(f, **widgetdict)
```